# Under what conditions nullspace of a matrix $C = AB$ be guaranteed if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$; $m < n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I wonder, under what conditions nullspace of a matrix $C = AB$ be guaranteed if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$; $m < n$?

---

Attempt:

Since $\operatorname{rank}\left( C \right) \leq \min \left( \operatorname{rank}\left( A \right), \operatorname{rank}\left( B \right) \right)$, then one can always ensure having a low rank matrix either $A$ or $B$ such that $C$ always has nullspace. Does this argument make sense?

Comment: If $m<n$ then nullity$(B)\neq 0$ from rank nullity. Since $$\{0\}\subset N(B)\subseteq N(C)$$ we must have $N(C)$ containing more than just the zero vector. Note $C$ will *always* have a nullspace as it will always contain the zero vector.

Comment: The null space of $C$ is called the null *space* because it is a vector space. As a vector space, it has to have the $0$ vector in it. It does not make sense to exclude it. If you exclude it, you don't have a vector space anymore, whether you have other vectors in it or not. What you want to say is "When is the null space of $C$ not trivial" or "when is the nullity of $C > 0$" (i.e., the dimension of the null space of $C$). And as Matthew H. says, since $m < n$, this is always true.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for the enlightenment. Now, I understand better.

Comment: @MatthewH. Thank you for the comment.